# What triggers people to do competitive activities?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, consciousness

From my past I have seen some people who like to compete in games and try to be first(by games I mean all kind of games or hobbies such as video-games, sports etc. in which competition is included). I assume this kind of activity is needed when people have the need to know that they are equal with the others or to stay above average and be satisfied for what they can achieved.

What is your research is there about this and what actually triggers some people to compete more than others. Is it a nature or a nurture thing?

---

This obviously has to do with psychological matters which can't be analyzed to a detail and is some kind of a philosophical question but even though which is your opinion also links and studies on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Phil, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I admit my question is a little blurry nevertheless I want to say what is the thing or emotion and how it is nurtured in order to make someone competitive.

Comment: Want to add it to your question :) Interesting btw +1

Comment: you are right, also feel free to make any changes, I've changed it now hope it is now more eye-catching

Comment: Let me know if you are happy with the edit, you are free to rollback or edit it again, and I've seen you here before, nice to see you again :)

Comment: Thanks very much for all,I find this forum interesting and fascinating I personally love cognitive science and thanks again for the support :)

Comment: I think its just an urge to delay a pain that was bottled in the past. Saving the day.(for computer games). Being failed in real life makes one try to be best in game. Such as cheating or even using bugs of game.  If the player is just gifted, winning is inevitable even without cheating ^^ . We fall, to rise again.

Comment: I agree with that,that people assuming they have "lost" in real life try to be good in sth else like computer games.So from that it can be derived that a person has the tendency to be always good at something and not left behind from everything.So why it's that, is it a survival instinct to be good-competitive?Also I'll state that human in their life have to do something and by doing that they evolve themselves but if you agree with me what leads them to do this?In the begging it was food for survival instinct,so now food is not only the case, shelter,comforts are included.do you agree?

Comment: Yeas i agree with the primitive needs like food, life insurance(or security) and similar emergency.

Answer (score 3):

Culture, psychology and physiology (gender) all play an important role is determining ones willingness and ability to compete.

In one sense your nationality influences your desire to compete. Competition and conflict does not originate with Americans but we have fostered via our culture a society of those who [compete](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/wired-success/201208/why-do-we-have-obsession-winning). Human nature outside of modern social forces was largely [communal and cooperative based](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0395631254).

Psychologically speaking on an individual basis what techniques you know to handle competition will help you perform under the stress of competition but will [not itself cause you to be a better performer](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/bul/138/6/1071/). It seems the challenge or resistance causes development; not competition.

Testosterone and the male gender roles make competition easier for men. Men are less anxious to start competition. Being easier to start will cause more men to engage in competitive behavior than woman. (Even though women are [equally competitive](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9639863) once they begin). Men also outperform women on higher competitive test like college entrance exams where as women outperform men on high school exit exams.

> (a) attitudes toward competition (although men may feel comfortable performing in a competitive setting, women may be more anxious about such prospects), (b) beliefs about relative performance (men may be more confident that they are among the highest-performing participants and thus be more inclined to compete), and (c) risk and feedback aversion (the tournament is not only competitive but is also more uncertain and provides more information about relative performance than the piece-rate scheme; if women are more averse to such factors, they may be less inclined to select
>   competitive compensation).

-[Gender and Competition: Why do woman shy away from competition.](http://www.stanford.edu/~niederle/NV.AnnualReview.Print.pdf)